# Java: using short instead of int

Tags: java, short

I have written a function to test the use of short with java

```
public static short shortFactorial(short n)
{
    short lIndex = 1;
    short lResult = 1;

    for(lIndex = 1;lIndex <= n;lIndex++)
    {
        lResult = (short)(lIndex * lResult);
    }

    return(lResult);
}
```

I have called the function with the max size for a short, i.e.:

```
shortFactorial((short)33000)
```

can anyone tell me why the result is 1 ?

Comment: Short.MAX_VALUE = 32767, lIndex  is never lower than n, because n is overflowed to negative. hence you skip the loop and return 1.

Answer (score 3):

Since maximum value of `short` is 32767, `(short)33000` overflows to a negative value, and hence your loop doesn't iterate. As your initialization of `lResult = 1`, it returns 1.